# SEAndroid permission

Tags: android, selinux

I use SELinux like this :

```
SELinux.restoreconRecursive(new File("/data/data/com.my.app"));
```

and I got this failure:

```
07-27 19:21:11.890 W/SELinux ( 5182): SELinux:  Could not look up information for package com.my.app, cannot restorecon .
07-27 19:21:11.890 E/SELinux ( 5182): SELinux: Could not set context for /data/data/com.my.app:  Socket operation on non-socket
07-27 19:21:11.890 E/SELinux ( 5182): SELinux:  Could not read /data/data/com.my.app: Permission denied.
```

Before this operation ,the file is look like:

```
 drwxrwx--x u0_a126  u0_a126           u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 cache
```

and I use adb to restore default, it should be:

```
drwxrwx--x u0_a126  u0_a126           u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 cache
```

that is why use restorecon in my code. 
plz help me about this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I have already resolve this . 
because another SELinux permission :

```
allow backuprestore selinuxfs:file { write };
allow backuprestore kernel:security { check_context };
allow backuprestore app_data_file:dir { relabelfrom relabelto};
allow backuprestore app_data_file:file { relabelfrom relabelto};
```